# How to run a Perl program from a Python script, while receiving logs and avoiding crashes for script return code: -9

Tags: python-3.x, bash, docker, perl, alpine-linux

I am using Python to run a long (4-60 minutes runtime) Perl program with different inputs.
The Perl program is old and with the use warning commented out. Different inputs use different parts of the code.

```
# use warnings FATAL => 'all';
```

All inputs work when I run the CMD from bash!

```
perl -I/storage my_script_entance.pl --ex_config R....
```

Some inputs crash when I run them using Popen:

```
 run_script('perl -I/storage my_script_entance.pl --ex_config R....')


 def run_script(cmd):

    args = shlex.split(f'{cmd}')

    # p = sp.Popen(args, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

    p = sp.Popen(args, stderr=sp.PIPE)

    output, err = p.communicate()
    print(f'output: {output}')
    print(f'err: {err}')

    rc = p.returncode

    print(f"script return code: {rc}")
```

The crashes look like this:

```
output: None
err: b''
script return code: -9
```

they surface in many different places in the code

my environment is:
Kubernetes with Alpine Docker containers with:

- perl5 (revision 5 version 30 subversion 1)
- Python 3.8.2

Why is running the scripts from Popen different than running the scripts from bash?
Is there a way to run them identically.

I read Popen documentation and tried using the run function with check=False with this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48025875/i-want-to-check-whether-pythons-subprocess-succeeded-or-whether-an-error-occurr). but couldn't read the output error pipes.

I tried some options using pexpect but failed so far.

Is there a way to run the scripts as in bash and just print the standard output and error?

P.S

The reason I am using Python to start Perl is because of the superior Kafka library (Perl Kafka Library is flaky and rigid)

Comment: `args = shlex.split(f'{cmd}')` is not equivalent to what the shell does (though it happens to be for the specific (partial) command you posted.) If you have a shell command, you should invoke a shell! `args = [ 'sh', '-c', cmd ]`

Comment: Tip: Is there a reason to stringify `cmd`? Seems to me that `f'{cmd}'` should be simply be `cmd`.

Comment: `-9` means something sent a SIGKILL signal to the process. This is unlikely to be something the Perl program did to itself. Maybe the system is imposing some kind of resource limit?

Comment: @ikegami it seems you are right on the money about the args (i'm using bash for uniformity). the stringify is legacy and I removed it. I'm checking if the -9 are results of kubernetes or docker lack of resources or kills

Comment: @zdim It means that I don't have to wait for the program to finish to receive and print standard output. I have a lot of things going on at the same time and Perl interpreter is not verbose about the reasons for shut down! as ikegami suggested it might be that something is shutting the program instances down, due to lack of resources, style linux kill e.g. Perl interpreter, docker VM, macOS, Kubernetes  I am hot on that trail and will report. perhaps run is also capable of capturing standard and error outputs as they come along, I will report on that too

Comment: @zdim I will check and report

Comment: @zdim it appears that my example is non blocking. Perhaps because If I define stderr=sp.PIPE I stop getting logs perhaps because the pipe is clogged or a thread is waiting on another thread for join

Comment: (given the developments, my comments weren't of much use so I removed them to reduce clutter. just letting it be known since your responses to them are now hanging...)

Answer (score 2):

Ok @ikegami gave was right my problems were compounded:

- -9 return code was a violent shut down of the perl daemons perhaps by the docker VM or MacOs or ...
- I could only listen to standard output in my script.
- I was calling Perl from an unusual context.
- Any change e.g. `args = ['bash', '-c', cmd]` created buffers by perl and maybe Bash.

so I asked a friend and we came up with two solutions, namely:

1. Accessing the standard output after calling `wait()` and ignoring the blocking standard error.
2. Using Python selectors library to register both pipelines and separate them as they come.

Both only work if Perl is set to flush output immediately:

```
$| = 1;
```

here is an example perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
# use warnings FATAL => 'all';

use feature qw/say/;

use Try::Tiny;
use File::Basename;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;
use Data::Dumper;
use YAML::XS 'LoadFile';

use JSON::MaybeXS qw(encode_json decode_json);
use JSON qw();


$| = 1;

say("Abra dabra");

my $noise = 'Mooo';
# my $bot_init_args;

GetOptions(
    'noise=s' => \$noise,
    # 'bot_init_args=s' => \$bot_init_args
);

if (defined $noise) {

    my $limit = 5;

    print STDERR "something awful\n";

    for(my $i=0; $i < $limit; $i++){

        say("$i of $limit: $noise");
        sleep(2);
    }

    print STDERR "something embarrassing\n";

    sleep(2);

    exit 0;
}
```

And here are the two solutions in Python 3.82:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import shlex
import subprocess as sp

import selectors


def read_stdo(something):

    print('standard output')
    print(f'{type(something)}')
    print(something.decode("utf-8"))


def read_stderr(something):
    print('standard error')
    print(f'{type(something)}')
    print(something.decode("utf-8"))


def channel(cmd):

    args = shlex.split(cmd)

    sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()

    p = sp.Popen(args=args, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=0)

    sel.register(p.stdout, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=read_stdo)
    sel.register(p.stderr, selectors.EVENT_READ, data=read_stderr)

    while p.poll() is None:

        print(p.poll())
        events = sel.select()
        for key, mask in events:

            line = key.fileobj.readline()

            print(f'{type(line)}')
            key.data(line)

    return_val = p.wait()
    print(f'return val: {return_val}')
    # return lines


def run_script(cmd):

    print("Reading command Standard Output without listening to Standard Error")

    args = shlex.split(f'{cmd}')

    print(f'cmd: {cmd}')
    print(args)
    # p = sp.Popen(args=['/bin/bash', '-c', 'printenv;', ' sleep 25;', ' pwd'], stdout=sp.PIPE)
    p = sp.Popen(args=args, stderr=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, bufsize=0)

    line = p.stdout.readline()
    while line:
        print(line.decode("utf-8"))
        line = p.stdout.readline()
    # p = sp.run(['bash', '-c', cmd], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

    # output, err = p.communicate()
    # print(f'output: {output.decode("utf-8")}\n')

    # if err is not None:
    #     print(f'err: {err.decode("utf-8")}')

    p.wait()
    rc = p.returncode

    print(f"script return code: {rc}")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    _cmd = 'perl -I/storage /storage/annoyingPerl.pl --noise quack'
    run_script(_cmd)

    channel(f'{_cmd} barf')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) and running the Perl script through `bash` :

I first created a test Perl script `p.pl`:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

for my $i (0..$#ARGV) {
    my $arg = $ARGV[$i];
    say "ARG $i: $arg";
}
sleep 2;
say STDERR "STDERR: no errors";
sleep 1;
exit 2;
```

Then, the Python script:

```
import subprocess as sp

def main():
    cmd = R"""perl p.pl -input eggs.txt -output "spam spam.txt" -cmd "echo '$MONEY'"
    """
    #print(cmd)

    completed_proc = sp.run(['bash','-c', cmd], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

    print('output: {}'.format(completed_proc.stdout))
    print('err: {}'.format(completed_proc.stderr))
    print('script return code: {}'.format(completed_proc.returncode))

main()
```

**Output**:

```
output: b"ARG 0: -input\nARG 1: eggs.txt\nARG 2: -output\nARG 3: spam spam.txt\nARG 4: -cmd\nARG 5: echo ''\n"
err: b'STDERR: no errors\n'
script return code: 2
```

Comment: your answer disregards the "while receiving logs" part of my question + logs are condenced and new errors appear.

Comment: @RubberDuck What do you mean by *"while receiving logs"* ? Please give an example

Comment: @ Håkon Hægland my code above continuously writes sub process logs instead of waiting for it to finish

Comment: @RubberDuck It is still not clear what you mean. What is a sub process log? Is it log written from the Perl script to STDOUT or something else. Do you mean running the perl script as a background/daemon job and have the Python script log output as it becomes available?

Comment: Is it log written from the Perl script to STDOUT and printed by Python script during the process in near real time